# Form Checkbox behave like Radio Button in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

**Description**

I am working on vue project. I am getting stuck about making the Checkbox behave as Radio Button. Here is the code :

Components :

```
<b-table
              :items="table.items"
              :fields="fields"
              :busy="isBusy"
              class="border-0"
            >
              <template #cell(answer)="data">
                <template v-if="routerPathname === '/dashboards/donation/:id/update'">
                  <div
                    class="d-flex"
                    style="width: 300px; gap: 10px"
                  >
                    <BFormCheckbox
                        :checked="data.item.answer === 'YA'"
                        true-value="YA"
                        false-value=""
                        @change="handleCheckboxChange('YA', data.item.question_id)"
                    /> Ya
                <BFormCheckbox
                    :checked="data.item.answer === 'TIDAK'"

                    true-value="TIDAK"
                    false-value=""
                    @change="handleCheckboxChange('TIDAK', data.item.question_id)"
                /> Tidak

                <BFormCheckbox
                    :checked="data.item.answer === 'isian perawat jika diperlukan'"
                    true-value="isian perawat jika diperlukan"
                    false-value=""
                    @change="handleCheckboxChange('isian perawat jika diperlukan', data.item.question_id)"
                /> Petugas
              </div>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              {{ data.item.answer }}
            </template>
          </template>

          <template #table-busy>
            <div class="hp-p1-body text-center my-2">
              <b-spinner class="align-middle mr-8" />
              <strong>Memuat...</strong>
            </div>
          </template>
        </b-table>
        <p>Hasil {{ table.to }} dari {{ table.total }}</p>
```

mixins :

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      table: {
        debounceTimer: null,
        loading: false,
        pageOptions: [10, 25, 50, 100],
        page: 1,
        currentPage: 1,
        perPage: 5,
        total: 0,
        from: 0,
        to: 0,
        search: '',
        name: '',
        items: [],
        dataReservation: {
          date: '',
          location: '',
        },
        state: {
          selectedDate: '',
          selectedLocation: '',
        },
        locations: [],
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calculateRowNumber(index) {
      // Calculate the row number based on the current page and number of items per page
      return (this.table.currentPage - 1) * this.table.perPage + index + 1
    },
    transformColumns(columns = []) {
      this.table.fields = columns

      this.table.filtered = columns.filter(col => col.filtered).map(col => col.key)
    },
    getTableNumber(index) {
      const indexed = (this.table.currentPage - 1) * this.table.PerPage
      return index + indexed + 1
    },
    onChangeSearchTable(search) {
      this.table.search = search
    },
    onFilteredTable(filteredItems) {
      console.log(filteredItems)
      this.table.total = filteredItems.length
      this.table.currentPage = 1
    },
  },
}
```

method :

```
  handleCheckboxChange(key, index) {
      const value = key;

      // Set semua nilai yang sesuai dengan kunci ke nilai false
      Object.keys(this.checkedValues).forEach(k => {
        if (k !== key) {
          this.checkedValues[k] = false;
        }
      });

      // Set nilai untuk kunci yang dipilih
      this.checkedValues[key] = true;

      if (!Array.isArray(this.data_answer)) {
        this.data_answer = [];
      }

      const existingItemIndex = this.data_answer.findIndex(item => item.question_id === index);

      if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
        this.data_answer[existingItemIndex].answer = value;
      } else {
        this.data_answer.push({ question_id: index, answer: value });
      }

      console.log(this.data_answer);
    }
```

**Question** :

1. How to make form checkbox behave as radio button but when condition default value 'isian perawat jika diperlukan' has checked, so i can change the value ?
2. When 'isian perawat jika diperlukan' is unchecked, i can't edit the checkbox 'YA' and 'TIDAK'

i really need help. thanks in advance

Comment: If you want it to behave like a radio button, why not just use a radio button?